# Need guidance on performing Webservices security testing of WS-Security SOAP using using BURP

Tags: web-services, security, burp

We just started off with BURP for the web application. We use SOAP UI for WS-Security SOAP Web services. We are planning to extend the security testing to SOAP Web services using BURP. Can you kindly provide any directions on how can we achieve this. Thanks

Comment: This questions isn't a great fit for Stack Overflow. It might work on Security Stack Exchange, or you can email support@portswigger.net

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information on directly accessing the web service requests in BURP. We need to have a proxy(SOAP UI) to intercept the request. Below is the link for additional details.
http://www.fishofprey.com/2013/01/using-burp-suite-to-test-web-service.html